# Verify database id in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to verify if an index is a valid firebase generated id via Cloud Functions Security Rules? Example:

"-LGW9Zx_UAcQdDL9SVE8" - This is a valid id
"foobar123" - This is not a valid id

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"?

Comment: When firebase generates an id (with push() for example) it has a specific pattern and I wonder if we are able to check if the id is a generated firebase id or not. I added a bit more relevant infos to the question.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/mikelehen/3596a30bd69384624c11